# What is the final version of Logic Pro X and Final Cut Pro that works on macOS Mojave?

Tags: final-cut-pro, logic

What is the final version of Logic Pro X and Final Cut Pro that works on macOS Mojave? I currently have Logic Pro X 10.5.1 and Final Cut Pro 10.4.10. I don't want to upgrade past Mojave to use newer versions because I have a couple of 32-bit apps that will no longer work if I were to upgrade.

Comment: If you have already purchased Logic, then the App Store should only offer you the latest version that are compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The App Store update process should only offer you the latest version of FCPX that is compatible with your system.

According to [Apple's FCPX book](https://books.apple.com/gb/book/final-cut-pro-user-guide/id976299089), Final Cut Pro version 10.5 is the one that introduced a new minimum requirement of macOS 10.15 (Catalina). This is the one that dropped 32-bit support.

Your Mojave installation should therefore be offered nothing after FCPX version 10.4 (10.4.9 or 10).
FCPX version 10.4.6 was the one that introduced scanning your libraries for media using 32-bit codecs and warning you that support would soon be dropped (in FCPX version 10.5), so if you already have 10.4.10 or 10.4.9 then that's as far as it will go on your system.

Answer (score 2):

If you already own the apps, then if there are newer versions you can use, they will be offered in the App Store app. If nothing is offered, you have the latest versions.

If you don't already own them, you will need to purchase them on a newer Mac, compatible with the current versions, then when you go to Purchased on Mojave, it will then offer the latest versions you can run. There is, unfortunately, no way round this requirement.